# Mysql query won't work with a null column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null

I'm doing a relatively simple mysql query:

```
         SELECT g.id FROM myTable g
            WHERE g.timestamp > '0' 
            AND g.userId = '1'
            AND g.foo != '34'
            ORDER BY g.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

This query returns 0 rows, however if I remove the last condition, i.e change it to:

```
         SELECT g.id FROM myTable g
            WHERE g.timestamp > '0' 
            AND g.userId = '1'
            ORDER BY g.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

That returns 5-6 rows. This is very strange to me, since in all of those rows, the `int` column `foo` is set to NULL

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing something wilh `NULL` will result in `unknown`. That is why `NULL` values have to be compared with the `IS` operator.

Replace

```
AND g.repostVia != '34'
```

with

```
AND (g.repostVia != '34' or g.repostVia  is null)
```

or use the [NULL-safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) (thanks to eggyal):

```
AND NOT g.repostVia <=> '34'
```

Comment: Should be AND (g.repostVia != '34' or g.repostVia  is null)

Comment: Or one can use the [`NULL`-safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to): `AND NOT g.repostVia <=> '34'`

Comment: @eggyal: Learned something new. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison `g.repostVia != '34'` is `FALSE` when `g.repostVia` is `NULL` because any comparison with NULL will allways be FALSE.

You should make sure that you have covered this case (variable is `NULL`) in any comparison with NULL-able column.

You can use [IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) operator:

```
SELECT g.id FROM myTable g
            WHERE g.timestamp > '0' 
            AND g.userId = '1'
            AND (g.repostVia, != '34' OR g.repostVia IS NULL)
            ORDER BY g.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

or [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
SELECT g.id FROM myTable g
            WHERE g.timestamp > '0' 
            AND g.userId = '1'
            AND COALESCE(g.repostVia, -1) != '34'
            ORDER BY g.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I myself prefer COALESCE, because it seems to me that it retains the original meaning of comparison better and as it allows more parameters it is also more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `<>` instead of `!=`.

`0` values are tricky.

Comment: `<>` and `!=` are equivalent in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the comparison using IS NULL is definitely valid.  I want to offer that COALESCE() is often a bit more readable, if you have an invalid value that you can assign.  For instance, if g.foo is always positive, then the following would work:

```
     SELECT g.id FROM myTable g
         WHERE g.timestamp > '0'
          AND g.userId = '1'
         AND coalesce(g.foo, -1) != '34'
         ORDER BY g.id DESC
     LIMIT 0, 10
```